# Why can't I call a class's non-default constructor in another file?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am fairly new to C++. I have started writing a class called Row, and I am trying to call a non-default constructor to create a row object in a separate main.cpp file, but I keep getting an error that I do not understand. Can anyone explain to me what I've done wrong?

Here are my three files:

Row.h

```
#ifndef ROW_H
#define ROW_H
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

class Row {
    std::vector<int> row;
public:
    // constructor
    Row(std::vector<int> row);
};

#endif
```

Row.cpp

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include "Row.h"

// constructor
Row::Row(std::vector<int> row_arg) {
    row = row_arg;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include "Row.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    Row row(v);
    return 0;
}
```

The error I receive upon trying to compile main.cpp is this:

```
/tmp/ccJvGzEW.o:pascal_classes.cpp:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `Row::Row(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)'
/tmp/ccJvGzEW.o:pascal_classes.cpp:(.text+0x71): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Row::Row(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a linker error, not a compiler error, and my guess is that you're getting this error because either

1. you forgot to compile `Row.cpp`, or
2. you forgot to link `Row.o` into the final executable.

If you're compiling from the command-line, make sure to compile both `main.cpp` and `Row.cpp`. That should fix things!

Comment: That totally did it. I didn't realize I had to compile both .cpp files. Thank you!